# How do I adjust my regex to only replace abbreviations and not the expansions?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I fix this regex, to not touch the expansions like `HYDRAULIC` and only convert `HYD` and `HYD.` to `HYDRAULIC` and fix the space issue (for `HYD.CYLINDER`)?

[Link of regex](https://regex101.com/r/9TVuPn/9)

Regex (`hyd.` and `hyd`):

```
\b(hyd)(?:\s|$|[^\w])
```

Test String:

```
HYD. CYLINDER
HYD CYLINDER
HYD.CYLINDER
HYDRAULIC CYLINDER
CYLINDER,HYD.
CYLINDER,HYDRAULIC
CYLINDER,HYD
CYLINDER, HYD.
CYLINDER, HYDRAULIC
CYLINDER,HYD
```

Substition:

```
HYDRAULIC

HYDRAULIC CYLINDER
HYDRAULICCYLINDER
HYDRAULICCYLINDER
HYDRAULIC CYLINDER
CYLINDER,HYDRAULIC
CYLINDER,HYDRAULIC
CYLINDER,HYDRAULICCYLINDER, HYDRAULIC
CYLINDER, HYDRAULIC
CYLINDER,HYDRAULIC
```

Comment: Is your `Substitution` the expected output, or, what is?

Comment: Try `\bhyd(?:\.|\b)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wbl5BK/1). At the end of `hyd`, you check for dot or word boundary.

Comment: Or try `\bhyd\b\.?`  https://regex101.com/r/AglX1i/2

Comment: If you want to insert a space where it is missing before a letter or digit, try `s.replace(/\bhyd(?:\.|\b)([a-z0-9]?)/gi, function($0, $1) { return "HYDRAULIC" + ($1 ? " " + $1 : "") ; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replace(/\bhyd(?:\.|\b)([a-z0-9]?)/gi, function($0, $1) { 
    return "HYDRAULIC" + ($1 ? " " + $1 : "") ; 
})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wbl5BK/2).

**Regex details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `hyd` - a substring
- `(?:\.|\b)` - a dot or word boundary
- `([a-z0-9]?)` - Capturing group 1: an optional alphanumeric char.

If Group 1 matches, the match is replaced with `HYDRAULIC` + space + the letter captured in Group 1, else, it is replaced with just `HYDRAULIC`.

Note that `\bhyd(?:\.|\b)` and `\bhyd\b\.?` [suggested by The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469437/how-do-i-adjust-my-regex-to-only-replacing-expansions-and-not-the-abbreviations/55469728#comment97650215_55469437) are synonymous.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['HYD. CYLINDER','HYD CYLINDER','HYD.CYLINDER','HYDRAULIC CYLINDER','CYLINDER,HYD.','CYLINDER,HYDRAULIC','CYLINDER,HYD','CYLINDER, HYD.','CYLINDER, HYDRAULIC','CYLINDER,HYD'];
var rx = /\bhyd(?:\.|\b)([a-z0-9]?)/gi;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.replace(rx, function($0, $1) { 
    return "HYDRAULIC" + ($1 ? " " + $1 : "") ; 
  }))
}
```

Comment: /\bhyd(?:\.|\b)([a-z0-9]?)/gi; how do I include an variable instead of a string "hyd" in the regex?

Comment: @IsakLaFleur `var rx = new RegExp("\\b" + term + "(?:\\.|\\b)([a-z0-9]?)", "gi")`, it is a [commonly asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035) on SO. If your term can contain special chars, ["escape" the term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493), `term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')`. If the term can start / end with special chars, you cannot rely on `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

One way: probably not the best is to use this regex:

```
\b(hyd\.?)(?:\s|$|[^\w])
```

and sub with "HYDRAULIC " with space at the end

Answer (score 0):

Just use this pattern: `\b(hyd)\W+`

Only new is `\W+` - matches one or more non-word characters.

Then substitute it with `HYDRAULIC` (note space at the end!).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9TVuPn/10)